# Using rand() and srand() in an encryption code

Tags: c++, encryption, random, codeblocks, srand

The question wants me to program a One-Time-Small Pad cryptosystem where the message is longer than the key. the program will use srand() and rand() to generate numbers from 0 to 4 (if the key has 5 letters) and use them on the whole sentence. the srand uses the seed which is the sum of the ASCII values of the letters of the initial key. The problem now is that the sentence encrypted is not the same as the example (attached below).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string message, key;
    int messagevalue, keyvalue, i=0, j=0, seed=0;


    cout<<"Enter the message: ";

    getline(cin, message);

    cout << "Enter the key: ";

    getline(cin, key);

    messagevalue = message.length();
    keyvalue = key.length();

    while (key[i] != 0)
    {
        i++;
        j++;
    }


    cout << "The message is: " << setw(20)  << message << endl;

    for (i=0; i < messagevalue; i++)
    {
       seed = seed + key[i];
    }

    srand(seed);

    for(i=0; i < messagevalue; i++)
    {

    message[i] = 65 + (message[i] + key[rand()%j]) % 26;

    }

    cout <<"The cipher is: " << setw(21)  << message <<endl;


    for(i=0; i < messagevalue; i++)
    {
      message[i] = 65 + 26 + (message[i] - key[rand()%j]) % 26;

      if ((message[i] - key[i]) >= 0)
      {
          message[i] = message[i] - 26;
      }

    }

    cout << "The message again is: " << setw(14)  << message << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see what the difference is between your input and deciphered message. Or is that what it's meant to be, but you are not getting that? If so, can you post what YOUR code produces?

Comment: yea that's a sample of how it should be. 

im getting  UIWUMTOUVWHHJHJFQGIXWOSDCWQKIYIV and the decrypted is even worse

Comment: There is no reason to expect the encrypted text to be the same as the sample, unless you're using the same compiler and runtime library as whoever created the sample. You should, of course, be able to get the original text back.

Comment: Be aware that `srand()` and `rand()` are **not suitable** for serious encryption. If you're doing non-serious encryption, they're ok.

Comment: @KeithThompson it's a homework actually

Comment: If the key is smaller than the message then this is technically not a One-Time Pad and therefore not perfectly secure (if used with a CSPRNG).

Answer (score 0):

The code should call `srand(seed)` again, after encrypting the message and before decrypting it so that `rand()` will generate the same sequence of values when decrypting as it did when encrypting.

Note also that that loop with `i++` and `j++` is just setting `i` and `j` to `key.length()`. Then the code throws away the new value of `i`.

Note, too, that it's bad practice to define all your variables at the top of the function when they aren't used until much later. Define variables at their point of first use, and initialize them as part of their definition. So, for example, instead of

```
int messagevalue;
.
.
.
messagevalue = message.length();
```

use

```
int messagevalue = message.length();
```

And, finally, a better name for `messagevalue` would be `message_length`, since that's what it actually holds.

Comment: thank you so much for the tips! i tried putting the srand before the decrypting and it didn't produce the same message again.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i < messagevalue; i++)
{
   seed = seed + key[i];
}
```

`key` is shorter than `message`, so `key[i]` is out of bounds access. Should be

```
for (i=0; i < keyvalue; i++)
{
   seed = seed + key[i];
}
```

Comment: That actually worked perfectly!! thanks alot. but the decrypting message is still not the same.